# Could not load file or assembly 'Venetasoft.WP.Net.SMTP, Version=1.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies

Tags: windows-phone-8

I used mailmessage service for sending mails with attachments in windows phone 8 app.
For this i need dll Venetasoft.WP.Net.SMTP.
So i added reference to that.
It is working fine when we run project in debug mode.
getting following exception when i xap it.
Could not load file or assembly 'Venetasoft.WP.Net.SMTP, Version=1.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
Why i am getting that exception?
Please help me.
Reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Expand your project References item, find Venetasoft.WP.Net.SMTP, right click the item, and choose Properties (this may already be displayed on the lower right of your IDE). Ensure that **Copy Local** is set to **True**, otherwise the library will not be packaged with your XAP.

Comment: @user1934329 Best idea I've got. You might try a clean and rebuild, but I don't expect that would resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

With version 1.3.1 the error is gone for me. Remember that with the new version there are some changes in the API.